# Mysql auto fill field based on value of other field

Tags: mysql

I have created this database in MYSQL.

Category_Name is a "set" column. When I select "Projects" in the Category_Name column, is it possible to make the "Category Number" AUTOMATICALLY be 11? Same applies for Crafts to be 10 etc..

Any ideas?
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Your data structure is wrong.

You want a `Categories` table, such as:

```
create table categories (
    Category_Number int not null primary key,
    Category_Name varchar(255) not null
);
```

Then, in your table, you should only keep `Category_Number` and use `JOIN` to get the name.  This is one step in normalizing the data.